# Как растянуть элемент на всю высоту flex

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Я хочу растянуть `«` и `»` на всю ширину flex-контейнера, но не понимаю как, вот код, который отвечает за flex-контейнер `.calendar__top`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.calendar__top {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--gray);
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

А вот css, который отвечает за `«` и `»`

```css
.calendar__right, .calendar__left {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Я это хочу сделать, чтобы можно было удобно кликать по элементу, чтобы он занимал всю высоту и пользователь не искал место, куда попасть
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я привожу всю свою верстку, чтобы можно было посмотреть(календарь внизу)

```js
Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
  return 33 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 33).getDate();
};
let calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar');
let weeks = [...calendar.querySelectorAll('.week')];
let calendar__month = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__month');
let calendar__year = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__year');
let calendar__left = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__left');
let calendar__right = calendar.querySelector('.calendar__right');
let calendarNumber = 0;

calendar__left.addEventListener('click', () => {
  calendarNumber--;
  clearDays();
  logicCalendar(calendarNumber);
});

calendar__right.addEventListener('click', () => {
  calendarNumber++;
  clearDays();
  logicCalendar(calendarNumber);
});

let days = [];
for (let i = 0; i < weeks.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < weeks[i].children.length; j++) {
    days.push(weeks[i].children[j]);
  }
}
let months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
let thisMonth = function(month) {
  return months[month];
};

function logicCalendar(calendarNum) {
  let thisDate = new Date();
  if (calendarNum !== undefined) {
    thisDate.setMonth(thisDate.getMonth() + calendarNum);
  }
  let thisYear = thisDate.getFullYear();
  let thisDay = thisDate.getDate();
  thisDate.setDate(1);
  let dayWeek = thisDate.getDay();
  if (dayWeek == 0) {
    dayWeek = 6;
  } else {
    dayWeek--;
  }
  thisDate.setDate(thisDay);
  let daysClone = days.slice();
  daysClone.splice(0, dayWeek);
  let day = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < thisDate.daysInMonth(); i++) {
    daysClone[i].innerHTML = day;
    day++;
  }
  if (calendarNum === undefined || calendarNum === 0) {
    daysClone[thisDay - 1].classList.add('today');
  }
  calendar__month.innerHTML = thisMonth(thisDate.getMonth());
  calendar__year.innerHTML = thisYear;
}

function clearDays() {
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    days[i].innerHTML = '';
    if (days[i].classList.contains('today')) {
      days[i].classList.remove('today');
    }
  }
}

logicCalendar();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

/* 
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 */

:root {
  --gray: #333333;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*************** 

INTRO

****************/

.intro {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  height: 103vh;
  margin-top: -3vh;
}

.intro__text {
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}


/*************** 

CONTENT

****************/

.content {
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.content__blocks {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}


/*************** 

LEFT__BLOCK

****************/

.left__block {
  width: 70%;
}

.post__media {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.post__media__right {
  min-width: 400px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.post__media__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.post__media__text {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.post__media__text a {
  color: #3673b5;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .05s linear;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.post__media__text a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.post__media__info {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.post__media__info div {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__section {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .15s linear, -webkit-box-shadow .15s linear, -moz-box-shadow .15s linear;
}

.post__section:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}

.post__date {
  min-width: 90px;
}

.post__tags {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post__tags a {
  border: 1px solid #a3a4a6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .15s linear, -webkit-box-shadow .15s linear, -moz-box-shadow .15s linear;
}

.post__tags a:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 37px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}


/*************** 

RIGHT__BLOCK

****************/

.right__block {
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right__block>div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.title__comments {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--gray);
  padding: 15px 0;
}


/*************** 

COMMENT

****************/

.comment {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.comment__img {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.comment__text {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.comment__article {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.comment__in__article {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.comment__author {
  margin-top: auto;
}


/*************** 

CATEGORIES

****************/

.categories__title {
  background-color: var(--gray);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.categories {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.categories__name {
  padding: 7px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out, color .2s ease-in-out, padding-left .2s ease-in-out, border-bottom .2s ease-in-out;
}

.categories__name:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.categories__name:hover {
  background-color: var(--gray);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}


/*************** 

CALENDAR

****************/

.calendar__top {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--gray);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.calendar__right,
.calendar__left {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.day__week {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.day__month {
  border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-top: 0;
}

.week {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.week>div {
  background-color: #f3f2f2;
  flex: 1;
  height: 40px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.week>div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.week:not(:last-child) div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

div.today {
  background-color: #ee5728;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 1130px) {
  .content__blocks {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .right__block {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .title__comments,
  .categories__title {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .comment {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .left__block {
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* @media (max-width: 430px) {
    
} */

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .post__media {
    height: auto;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .post__media__left {
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .post__media__left img {
    max-height: 400px;
  }
  .post__media__right {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .post__media__right {
    min-width: auto;
  }
  .post__media__title {
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
  .post__media__info {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .post__date,
  .post__section {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .comment__text {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .comment__img {
    display: none;
  }
  .week>div {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .post__media__title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>News</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__text">
        News & Articles
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content__blocks">
        <div class="left__block">
          <div class="posts__block">

            <div class="post__media">
              <div class="post__media__left">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="post__media__right">
                <div class="post__media__title">
                  My awesome sticky post
                </div>
                <div class="post__media__info">
                  <div class="post__date">19 ноя в 16:30</div>
                  <a href="#" class="post__section">Инвестиции</a>
                </div>
                <div class="post__media__text">
                  One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly,<a href="#"> ...continue reading</a>
                </div>
                <div class="post__tags">
                  <a href="#">IT</a>
                  <a href="#">Amazon</a>
                  <a href="#">Big Data</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- .post__media__right -->
            </div>
            <!-- .post__media -->

            <div class="post__media">
              <div class="post__media__left">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/600" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="post__media__right">
                <div class="post__media__title">
                  My awesome sticky post
                </div>
                <div class="post__media__info">
                  <div class="post__date">19 ноя в 16:30</div>
                  <a href="#" class="post__section">Инвестиции</a>
                </div>
                <div class="post__media__text">
                  One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly<a href="#"> ...continue reading</a>
                </div>
                <div class="post__tags">
                  <a href="#">IT</a>
                  <a href="#">Amazon</a>
                  <a href="#">Big Data</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- .post__media__right -->
            </div>
            <!-- .post__media -->

          </div>
          <!-- .posts__block -->
        </div>
        <!-- .left__block -->

        <div class="right__block">
          <div class="latest__comments">
            <div class="title__comments">
              Последние комментарии
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="comment">
              <div class="comment__img">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="comment__text">
                <div class="comment__article">
                  My awesome sticky post
                </div>
                <div class="comment__in__article">
                  Я думаю, что это должно быть по другому
                </div>
                <div class="comment__author">
                  Михаил
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="categories__block">
            <div class="categories__title">
              Разделы
            </div>

            <div class="categories">
              <a href="#" class="categories__name">Финансовая грамотность</a>
              <a href="#" class="categories__name">Акции</a>
              <a href="#" class="categories__name">Облигации</a>
              <a href="#" class="categories__name">Саморазвитие</a>
              <a href="#" class="categories__name">Спорт</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- .categories__block -->

          <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar__top">
              <div class="calendar__left">«</div>
              <div class="calendar__date">
                <span class="calendar__month"></span>
                <span class="calendar__year"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="calendar__right">»</div>
            </div>
            <div class="day__week">
              <div>Пн</div>
              <div>Вт</div>
              <div>Ср</div>
              <div>Чт</div>
              <div>Пт</div>
              <div>Сб</div>
              <div>Вс</div>
            </div>
            <div class="day__month">
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
              <div class="week">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- .calendar -->

        </div>
        <!-- .right__block -->

      </div>
      <!-- .content__blocks -->
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </main>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: чтобы можно было удобно кликать по элементу. 
Как вариант добавь просто падинги, визуально останется также, но при наведении просто область клика увеличиться.

Comment: @faradei да, такое приходило в голову, но я бы хотел задать высоту типа 100%, чтобы это было универсально, чтобы не надо было задавать пиксели вручную

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Так проблема в высоте или ширине? Если в высоте, я бы у родителя убрал паддинги, поставил ему руками высоту нужную (40px), а внутренним блокам - высота 40px line-height 40px. На самом деле, Вы же паддинги-то задаете вручную (10px).

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов да, я как раз понял, что внутренним элементам можно просто задать паддинги)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно убрать отступы у контейнера `.calendar__top`

```css
.calendar__top {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--gray);
}
```

И задать их `«` и `»`

```css
.calendar__right, .calendar__left {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```